# CSS wildcards in attributes

Tags: html, css

I ran accross this:

```
#id {
    width: 73.076em;
    *width: 71.25em;
}
```

What does the wildcard mean? I can't seem to quickly google my way out of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` rule **IS ONLY** picked up by Internet Explorer.. It's a [CSS hack](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml#unrecommended-asterisk_prefix).

> `*property: value` applies the property value in **IE 7 and below**. It may or may not work in future versions. Warning: this uses **invalid CSS**.

Comment: Just to be clear: It isn't a wildcard, it is an invalid character that old IE (incorrectly) ignores.

Answer (score 2):

@Phil is correct - `*property: value` is a CSS hack that will only be applied in IE7 and lower.

I'd like to link to this article: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#css-hacks

> Both the `_property: value` and `*property: value` hacks (as seen in
>   the above code block) are examples of safe CSS hacks. They were
>   discovered, identified as bugs, and patched in a browser update. Since
>   then, it’s very likely that Microsoft and other browser vendors added
>   checks for these CSS hacks to their layout tests, to make sure no new
>   browser version is shipped with a regression this significant.